# Reachability issue on swift 3(xCode8-beta6)

Tags: reachability, swift3, xcode8-beta6

I am currently developing a project using Reachability library in xCode8 beta6(swift3).
I think I correctly implemented Reachability.swift into my project.

By the way, the app crashes in the following line of Reachability.swift when I call `reachability.startNotifier()`.

```
let reachability = Reachability()!
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reachabilityChanged:",name: ReachabilityChangedNotification,object: reachability)
    do{
      try reachability.startNotifier()
    }catch{
      print("could not start reachability notifier")
    }
```

[image]
Here is what I can see in the log.

> *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x10d939668 of class 'WebClient' does not implement
>   methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead Unrecognized selector
>   +[WebClient reachabilityChanged:]

Of course, I did implemented reachabilityChanged selector function.

```
func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification) {

        let reachability = note.object as! Reachability

        if reachability.isReachable {
            if self.pendingSurvey == true {
               ....
            }
        }
    }
```

I am spending much time to find the reason but I can not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3, Objective-C selector for `func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification)` becomes `reachabilityChangedWithNote:`. (This may be a little bit different in some betas.) So, the `Reachability` runtime cannot find the method for selector `reachabilityChange:` and crashes.

Usually you declare a Swift method for selector `reachabilityChange:` in Swift 3 as:

```
func reachabilityChanged(_ note: NSNotification) {
    //
}
```

Or using `@objc` is another way:

```
@objc(reachabilityChange:)
func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification) {
    //
}
```

Comment: I tried to update the code but it still doesn't work.

Comment: it causes a crash as usual.

Comment: it seems like Reachability still can not find reachabilityChanged: method.

Comment: @star99, you may have broken other parts while migrating, or Reachability may have some unknown incompatibility issue with Swift 3. Anyway, without your showing more context, I cannot say any more.